# Are mineable tokens possible?

Tags: contract-design, mining, tokens, erc-20

I'm a bit puzzled about the ethereum.org/token example which states [further down in the advanced examples](https://ethereum.org/token#proof-of-work) that it can be coupled to proof-of-work. I really like the idea of mining a token. The example looks something like this:

```
function giveBlockReward() {
  balanceOf[block.coinbase] += 1;
}
```

Now my question is, this looks like a honeypot for malicious inflation. Isn't it possible to execute `giveBlockReward()` multiple times per block? Would a simple mechanism to make sanity checks on blocknumber be sufficient to make this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should keep track of the last block to "mine" its reward to prevent abuse:

```
uint lastBlockRewarded;
function giveBlockReward() {
  if (lastBlockRewarded >= block.number) 
    throw;
  lastBlockRewarded = block.number;
  balanceOf[block.coinbase] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [EIP 918: Mineable Token Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-918). Proposed interface:

```
contract ERC918  {

   function mint(uint256 nonce) public returns (bool success);

   function getAdjustmentInterval() public view returns (uint);

   function getChallengeNumber() public view returns (bytes32);

   function getMiningDifficulty() public view returns (uint);

   function getMiningTarget() public view returns (uint);

   function getMiningReward() public view returns (uint);

   function hash(uint256 _nonce, address _minter) public returns (bytes32 digest);

   function _reward(address _minter) internal returns (uint);

   function _epoch() internal returns (uint);

   function _adjustDifficulty() internal returns (uint);

   event Mint(address indexed from, uint rewardAmount, uint epochCount, bytes32 newChallengeNumber);
}
```